# Why does python come up with a TypeError even though I converted to strings?

Tags: python

So I created a Player and Dealer class for my blackjack game, but when I put the integer I want to print in an f-string, it comes up with a TypeError:

in results

```
print(f"{name}'s hand is {Player.hand}, total is {sum(Player.hand_val)}") 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

It's really confusing because I clearly printed it as a string. I also tried .format(), and str(), but they all showed up the same error message.

```py
class Player:
    wallet = 5000
    hand_val = []
    hand = []

    def __init__(self, wallet, hand_val=None, hand=None):
        self.wallet = wallet
        self.hand_val = hand_val
        self.hand = hand


class Dealer(Player):
    hand_val = []
    hand = []

    def __init__(self, hand_val, hand, wallet):
        super().__init__(hand_val, hand)
        self.hand_val = hand_val
        self.hand = hand

def cardgenerate():
    cards = [("A", 1), ("2", 2), ("3", 3), ("4", 4), ("5", 5), ("6", 6), ("7", 7), ("8", 8), ("9", 9), ("10", 10),
             ("J", 10), ("Q", 10), ("K", 10)]
    select = r.choice(cards)
    cardGen.append(select[0])
    cardGen_value.append(select[1])


cardGen = []
cardGen_value = []


def hit():
    for i in range(2):
        cardgenerate()
    # playerHand is from even indexes from cardGen[]
    Player.hand.append(cardGen[0])
    Player.hand_val.append(cardGen[0])

    # dealerHand is from odd indexes from cardGen[]
    Dealer.hand.append(cardGen[1])
    Dealer.hand_val.append(cardGen[1])

def stay():
    cardgenerate()
    Dealer.hand.append(cardGen[0])
    Dealer.hand_val.append(cardGen[0])


def pcheck_lose():
    if sum(Player.hand_val) > 21:
        print("BUST!!! You lost")
        Player.hand_val = []
        return True


def dcheck_lose():
    if sum(cardGen_value) > 21:
        print("THE DEALER BUSTED!!! You won")
        Dealer.hand_val = []
        return True


def results():
    print(f"{name}'s hand is {Player.hand}, total is {sum(Player.hand_val)}")
    print(f"Dealer's hand is {Dealer.hand}, total is {sum(Dealer.hand_val)}")
```

Comment: I'm guessing `hand_val` is a list of strings? you need to add the code for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

change this:

```
Player.hand_val.append(cardGen[0])
```

to

```
Player.hand_val.append(cardGen_value[0])
```

Comment: wow it worked lmao I feel so stupid... thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that `hand_val` list has only integer/float values, somewhere maybe during initialization you are providing it a string?

```
hand_val = ['30', 30]
print(sum(hand_val))
```

gives `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

```
hand_val = [30, 30]
print(sum(hand_val))
```

gives output of 60.

If you still want to provide string to the table, and then sum it up, you can cast value to integer type by using `int(<str_variable>)`

like so:

```
strg = '30'
print(type(int(strg)))
```

Output:
<class 'int'>

Comment: Nope... I printed out Player.hand_val and it showed up a list of integers, not strings

Comment: Please provide full code of initialization of object and using the function then.

Comment: ```
def cardgenerate():
    cards = [("A", 1), ("2", 2), ("3", 3), ("4", 4), ("5", 5), ("6", 6), ("7", 7), ("8", 8), ("9", 9), ("10", 10),
             ("J", 10), ("Q", 10), ("K", 10)]
    select = r.choice(cards)
    cardGen.append(select[0])
    cardGen_value.append(select[1])

cardGen = []
cardGen_value = []
def hit():
    for i in range(2):
        cardgenerate()
    # playerHand is from even indexes from cardGen[]
    Player.hand.append(cardGen[0])
    Player.hand_val.append(cardGen[0])

    Dealer.hand.append(cardGen[1])
    Dealer.hand_val.append(cardGen[1])

```

Comment: ```
def stay():
    cardgenerate()
    Dealer.hand.append(cardGen[0])
    Dealer.hand_val.append(cardGen[0])


def pcheck_lose():
    if sum(Player.hand_val) > 21:
        print("BUST!!! You lost")
        Player.hand_val = []
        return True


def dcheck_lose():
    if sum(cardGen_value) > 21:
        print("THE DEALER BUSTED!!! You won")
        Dealer.hand_val = []
        return True


def results():
    print(f"{name}'s hand is {Player.hand}, total is {sum(Player.hand_val)}")
    print(f"Dealer's hand is {Dealer.hand}, total is {sum(Dealer.hand_val)}")
```

Comment: RIP readability

Comment: You could just edit original post.

Comment: yeah i realised sorry

Comment: its done, i edited it